# Cosmosdb spring boot sdk setting x-ms-max-item-count

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, azure-java-sdk

How can I set `x-ms-max-item-count` from java sdk?

is there an option to set page size to retrieve documents? currently it is limited to 100, i would like to increase it to 1000? how can i do it through the java SDK?

I am using `ReactiveCosmosTemplate` and have a bean of `CosmosClientBuilder` that I configure connection and consistency level.

But I cant find the max-item-count for a query. 100 batches is very small for me, I need to increase it. How can I do that?

I couldnt find it anywhere.

Comment: Hi DarthVader could you please share you reason for setting "x-ms-max-item-count"? Also, are you looking to do that in the Base java SDK and/or in reactive spring repository?

Comment: Done it already. cause it is getting batches of 100 docs for a query. with reactive was able to do it with byPage(token, size). One caveat is that, I had to block first otherwise returns all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x-ms-max-item-count cannot be directly set but can only be set using CosmosPagedFluX#byPage API in the java V4 SDK.

In non-reactive spring repository this can be set using the “pageSize” in CosmosPageRequest object. Please review the Pagination section in this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/read-data-spring-azure-cosmos-db-v3/)

In reactive spring repository there is no way of setting "x-ms-max-item-count.